# integrity constraint parent key not found oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

here are my tables

```
/*** SQLINES FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY ***/

CREATE USER test4 IDENTIFIED BY test4;

GRANT connect, resource, create view to test4;


ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = test4 ;
/* ------------ Owner ----------*/
DROP TABLE test4.Owner;


 CREATE TABLE test4.Owner (
  Owner_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Name VARCHAR2(40) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Phone_no VARCHAR2(12) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Email VARCHAR2(35) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Owner_ID)   );

 /* ------------ Owner END ----------*/

/* ------------ Language ----------*/
DROP TABLE test4.Language;


CREATE TABLE test4.Language (
  Owner_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  English CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Malay CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Arabic CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Tamil CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Mandarin CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Owner_ID)   ,
    FOREIGN KEY (Owner_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.Owner (Owner_ID));

/* ------------ Language end ----------*/ 

/* ------------ house ----------*/
DROP TABLE test4.House;


CREATE TABLE test4.House (
  House_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Owner_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Guest NUMBER(5) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Price NUMBER(10) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Booking_type VARCHAR2(9) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Type_of_rent VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  House_type VARCHAR2(15) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Address VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Date_from DATE DEFAULT sysdate NULL  ,
  Date_to DATE DEFAULT (sysdate+1) NULL  ,
  Popularity NUMBER(10) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL  ,
  Booking_ref VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Descr VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Title VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (House_ID)   ,
    FOREIGN KEY (Owner_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.Owner (Owner_ID));



/* ------------ house end----------*/

/* ------------ Neighbourhood ----------*/
DROP TABLE test4.Neighbourhood;


CREATE TABLE test4.Neighbourhood (
  House_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Airport CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Beach CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Mall CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Mosque CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Musolla CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PasarMalam CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (House_ID)   ,
    FOREIGN KEY (House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.House (House_ID));


/* ------------ Neighbourhood end----------*/ 


/* ------------ Room ----------*/
DROP TABLE test4.Room;



CREATE TABLE test4.Room (
  House_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Room_No VARCHAR2(50) NULL  ,
  Guest NUMBER(5) NOT NULL  ,
  Price NUMBER(10) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Booking_ref VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Date_from DATE DEFAULT sysdate NULL  ,
  Date_to DATE DEFAULT (sysdate+1) NULL  ,
  Descr VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Title VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Room_No, House_ID)   ,
    FOREIGN KEY (House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.House (House_ID));

/* ------------ Room end ----------*/

/* ------------ Guest ----------*/
DROP TABLE test4.Guest;



CREATE TABLE test4.Guest (
  Guest_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Name VARCHAR2(40) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Email VARCHAR2(35) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Room_No VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  House_ID VARCHAR2(7) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Booking_ref VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Guest_ID)   ,
    FOREIGN KEY (House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.House (House_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Room_No,House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.Room (Room_No,House_ID));

/* ------------ Guest end----------*/ 

/* ------------ Booking  ----------*/
DROP TABLE test4.Booking;


CREATE TABLE test4.Booking (
  Booking_ref VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL  ,
  Guest_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  House_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Room_No VARCHAR2(50) NULL  ,
  Check_In DATE DEFAULT sysdate NULL  ,
  Check_Out DATE DEFAULT (sysdate+1) NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Booking_ref)   ,
    FOREIGN KEY (House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.House (House_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Guest_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.Guest (Guest_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Room_No,House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.Room (Room_No,House_ID));


/* ------------ Booking  end ----------*/


/* ------------ Amenities  ----------*/
 DROP TABLE test4.Amenities;


CREATE TABLE test4.Amenities (
  House_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL  ,
  Room_No VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  TV CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  WiFi CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Kitchen CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  ACond CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Elevator CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  FireExtinguisher CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Gym CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Bed CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Bathroom CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Pool CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PetAllow CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  Wheelchair CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  SmokeDet CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL NULL  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (House_ID)   ,
    FOREIGN KEY (House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.House (House_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Room_No,House_ID)
    REFERENCES test4.Room (Room_No,House_ID));


/* ------------ Amenities end  ----------*/
```

until now everything is fine i have no problem creating them but when inserting values i face some errors and the most annoying one is **integrity constraint violated - parent key not found**

here is the SQL for inserting values into the tables :

```
/* ---------- Load Tables ------------- */

/* ---- Owner -------*/

INSERT INTO Owner VALUES ('OWN001', 'tartour', '0134578965', 'tartour@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Owner VALUES ('OWN002', 'tata aljiya', '01115698723', 'aljiya@yahoo.com');
INSERT INTO Owner VALUES ('OWN003', 'bedr adin', '0174589776', 'badrou@badrou.com');
INSERT INTO Owner VALUES ('OWN004', 'haziq bin malek', '0156235478', 'hazma@hotmail.com');
INSERT INTO Owner VALUES ('OWN005', 'fatima binti nourman', '0134587965', 'fatima45@yahoo.fr');
INSERT INTO Owner VALUES ('OWN006', 'saitama sensie', '0142365478', 'onepunch@calpedbaldy.com');
INSERT INTO Owner VALUES ('OWN007', 'kakashi sharingan', '01112547896', 'themasked@konoha.my');

/* ----- Owner End ------- */

/* ---- Language -------*/

INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('OWN001', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n','n');
INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('OWN002', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n','n');
INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('OWN003', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'y','n');
INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('OWN004', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n','n');
INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('OWN005', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n','n');
INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('OWN006', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n','y');
INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('OWN007', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y','y');

/* ---- Language End -------*/

/* ---- House -------*/

INSERT INTO House VALUES('H001', 'OWN001', NULL, NULL, 'Interval', 'Partial', 'Castle', 'bukit selengor', TO_DATE ('10/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('10/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H002', 'OWN004', 6, 100, 'Permanent', 'Full', 'House', 'Taman melati', TO_DATE ('10/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('10/11/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 5, 'B000000002', 'my house is the ultimate house you can ever dream of', 'the dream house');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H003', 'OWN006', NULL, NULL, 'Permanent', 'Partial', 'Apartment', 'City Z', TO_DATE ('10/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('10/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H004', 'OWN005', 5, 90, 'Interval', 'Full', 'House', 'Taman Seri Gombak', TO_DATE ('15/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('28/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 0, 'B000000004', 'I want to rent my house for a couple just for a month while I am out on a vacation', 'chinese house');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H005', 'OWN005', 4, 200, 'Permanent', 'Full', 'Condominium', 'Sri Cempaka', TO_DATE ('15/05/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('15/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 3, NULL, 'The view is perfect from the high bulding you can see the whole city and enjoy', 'fly in the sky');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H006', 'OWN001', 16, 500, 'Permanent', 'Full', 'Villa', 'ADDRESS', TO_DATE ('20/04/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('20/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2, NULL, 'Description', 'Title');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H007', 'OWN001', 8, 300, 'Permanent', 'Full', 'Bungalow', 'ADDRESS1', TO_DATE ('30/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('30/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 3, NULL, 'Description', 'Title');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H008', 'OWN001', 8, 300, 'Permanent', 'Full', 'Bungalow', 'ADDRESS1+1', TO_DATE ('30/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('30/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 4, NULL, 'Description', 'Title');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H009', 'OWN004', NULL, NULL, 'Permanent', 'Partial', 'House', 'ADDRESS', TO_DATE ('24/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('24/09/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), 5, NULL, 'Description', 'Title');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H010', 'OWN004', NULL, NULL, 'Permanent', 'Partial', 'Bungalow', 'ADDRESS', TO_DATE ('14/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('14/11/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 1, NULL, 'Description', 'Title');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H011', 'OWN002', 5, 180, 'Interval', 'Full', 'Terrace', 'ADDRESS', TO_DATE ('14/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('19/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 6, NULL, 'Description', 'Title');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H012', 'OWN003', 5, 120, 'Permanent', 'Full', 'House', 'ADDRESS', TO_DATE ('19/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('19/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 9, 'B000000005', 'Description', 'Title');
INSERT INTO House VALUES('H013', 'OWN007', 4, 250, 'Interval', 'Full', 'Condominium', 'Konoha village', TO_DATE ('14/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('19/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2, 'B000000007', 'I am goin for an S class mission for one month so i want to rent my Condominium', 'Anbu room');


/* ---- House end-------*/

/* ------------ Neighbourhood ----------*/

INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H001', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H002', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H003', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H004', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H005', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H006', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H007', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n','y', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H008', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H009', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n','y', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H010', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y','n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H011', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n','n', 'n');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H012', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n','n', 'n');
INSERT INTO Neighbourhood VALUES ('H013', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n','n', 'n');

/* ------------ Neighbourhood ----------*/

/* ------------ Room ----------*/


INSERT INTO Room VALUES ('H001', 'RM101', 16, 700, NULL, TO_DATE ('28/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('06/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'i have a luxurious big hall that can be booked for parties or big events or for filming', 'the luxurious Dinner hall');
INSERT INTO Room VALUES ('H001', 'RM102', 16, 700, 'B000000001', TO_DATE ('28/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('06/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'i have a luxurious big hall that can be booked for a luxurious night or for filming', 'the luxurious Master bedroom');
INSERT INTO Room VALUES ('H001', 'RM103', 16, 700, NULL, TO_DATE ('28/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('06/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'i have a luxurious big hall that can be booked for parties or big events or for filming', 'the luxurious hall');
INSERT INTO Room VALUES ('H003', 'RM301', 1, 45, 'B000000003', TO_DATE ('14/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('14/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'i am a hero for fun i will leave tomorrow problem to tomorrow me' , 'an average room for an average person');
INSERT INTO Room VALUES ('H010', 'RM1001', 3, 150, NULL, TO_DATE ('26/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('26/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'I am currently living in my Bungalow and I have an empty room to rent.' , 'Sleep-in a Bungalow');
INSERT INTO Room VALUES ('H009', 'RM901', 2, 70, 'B000000006', TO_DATE ('14/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('14/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'a nice small house that is perfect for starting your new life ;)' , 'A Fresh start');
INSERT INTO Room VALUES ('H009', 'RM902', 2, 70, NULL, TO_DATE ('14/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE ('14/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'a house that freshly renovated and upgraded' , 'cool staying');

/* ------------ Room end ----------*/

/* ------------ Guest ----------*/
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G001', 'Genos Kouhai', 'genos@hero.com', 'H003', 'RM301', 'B000000003');
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G002', 'Tony Fernandez', 'iamrich@money.com', 'H001', 'RM102', 'B000000001');
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G004', 'Cheong Lee Fatt', 'leechun@madeinchina.com', 'H004', NULL, 'B000000004');
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G003', 'Raju Mala', 'baju@klcc.my', 'H002', NULL, 'B000000002');
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G005', 'Al Saiid', 'yakho@gmail.com', 'H012', NULL, 'B000000005');
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G006', 'Jafri bin Hafiz', 'jafri@yahoo.com', 'H009', 'RM901', 'B000000006');
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G007', 'Sakura', 'sasuke02@konoha.com', 'H013', NULL, 'B000000007');

/* ------------ Guest end----------*/ 

/* ------------ Booking  ----------*/

INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000001', 'G002', 'H001', 'RM102', TO_DATE('05/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('09/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000002', 'G003', 'H002', NULL, TO_DATE('11/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('15/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000003', 'G001', 'H003', 'RM301', TO_DATE('11/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('11/05/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000004', 'G004', 'H004', NULL, TO_DATE('03/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('11/02/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000005', 'G005', 'H012', NULL, TO_DATE('11/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('04/02/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000006', 'G006', 'H009', 'RM901', TO_DATE('11/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('13/03/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000007', 'G007', 'H013', NULL, TO_DATE('16/11/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('09/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'));

/* ------------ Booking  end ----------* /


/* ------------ Amenities  ----------*/
/* haiqal, randomize the y and n but the bed should always be yes.*/
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H001', 'RM101', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H001', 'RM102', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H001', 'RM103', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H009', 'RM901', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H009', 'RM902', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H010', 'RM1001', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H003', 'RM301', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H002', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H004', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities  VALUES ('H005', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities  VALUES ('H006', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities  VALUES ('H007', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities  VALUES ('H008', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities  VALUES ('H011', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities  VALUES ('H012', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');
INSERT INTO Amenities  VALUES ('H013', NULL, 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y');

/* ------------ Amenities end  ----------*/
```

the errors are :

```
**INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G001', 'Genos Kouhai', 'genos@hero.com', 'H003', 'RM301', 'B000000003')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007729) violated - parent key not
found
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G002', 'Tony Fernandez', 'iamrich@money.com', 'H001', 'RM102', 'B000000001')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007729) violated - parent key not
found**


**
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G001', 'Genos Kouhai', 'genos@hero.com', 'H003', 'RM301', 'B000000003')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007729) violated - parent key not
found


INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G002', 'Tony Fernandez', 'iamrich@money.com', 'H001', 'RM102', 'B000000001')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007729) violated - parent key not
found



1 row created.


1 row created.


1 row created.

INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G006', 'Jafri bin Hafiz', 'jafri@yahoo.com', 'H009', 'RM901', 'B000000006')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007729) violated - parent key not
found



1 row created.

INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000001', 'G002', 'H001', 'RM102', TO_DATE('05/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('09/
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007735) violated - parent key not
found



1 row created.

INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000003', 'G001', 'H003', 'RM301', TO_DATE('11/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('11/
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007735) violated - parent key not
found



1 row created.


1 row created.

INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ( 'B000000006', 'G006', 'H009', 'RM901', TO_DATE('11/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_DATE('13/
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007735) violated - parent key not
found



1 row created.


1 row created.

INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H001', 'RM102', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007738) violated


INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H001', 'RM103', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007738) violated



1 row created.

INSERT INTO Amenities VALUES ('H009', 'RM902', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST4.SYS_C007738) violated
**
```

i don't understand why i have this ERRORS especially the one from guest table that says integrity constraint parent key not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certainly not going to go through every line you posted, as it may be that the errors in your first `insert` statements may be having a cascading effect onto the following `insert` statements.

But if I focus on your first error with the following `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G001', 'Genos Kouhai', 'genos@hero.com', 'H003', 'RM301', 'B000000003')
```

... it looks like you have inverted the `house_id` and `room_no` values.

To avoid this sort of mistake, it would be much better if you explicitly named the columns in your `insert` statement. Example:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3) values ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

... Oh, and little side note: don't be annoyed by these integrity constraint errors. Instead, be grateful that it prevented you from completely corrupting your data.

Comment: thank you @sstan it corrected most of the errors except amenities table errors any hint ?

Comment: You've defined the `house_id` as the primary key of the `amenities` table, but you are clearly inserting the same `house_id` value multiple times.  Is it possible that the primary key should be a different column or combination of columns?

Comment: thank you very much @sstan i inserted a new attribute as a primary key and it corrected everything

Comment: I would also add that it is awfully helpful to name your constraints rather than letting Oracle generate a name.  If your error message says that the constraint "fk_guest_house" was violated, for example, that's a much better clue that knowing that "SYS_C007738" was violated.  Now, you can look up what relationship SYS_C007738 enforces and figure it out but reasonable names make that sort of debugging much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
INSERT INTO Guest VALUES ('G001', 'Genos Kouhai', 'genos@hero.com',
           'H003', 'RM301', 'B000000003');
```

you are trying to insert house_id = 'RM301' that doesn't exist in  `House` tables.
Because there are foreign keys defined in `Geust` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Guest (
..... ,
    FOREIGN KEY (House_ID)
    REFERENCES House (House_ID),
....);
```

you are getting ORA-02291 error.